# How many slices that the segmented image contains in image segmentation using mat-lab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, image-segmentation

I need know that how many slices that the segmented image contains in image segmentation using mat-lab And also i want to know the size of single slice

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know how to answer without more details about the images you are working with.  If you have the image processing toolbox, you can load the image with:

```
IM = imread('your_image.tif');
```

Once you have your image loaded, you can figure out the size simply by:

```
size(IM)
```

For example, if you loaded a RGB image that was 512x512 pixels, the size() output would be (512, 512, 3), indicating that you have 3 planes, each 512 pixels by 512 pixels.